# Find the smallest natural number that has $1392$ positive divisors.

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest natural number that has $1392$  positive divisors.

We have $1392=2^4*3*29$ take that positive integer $n=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\dots p_k^{r_k}$

So we have $(r_1+1)(r_2+1)\dots (r_k+1)=2^4*3*29$.

For making $n$ the smallest possible amount we should have $p_i=2$ and $r_i+1=29m$ but the biggest problem is that  should we make $r_i$ so big or just take it $28$?The same problem was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888946/searching-smallest-number-that-has-40-distinct-positive-divisors).But there the number was small and we can check every possible case which is impossible here.So what should I do?

Comment: I think you should take $r_i=28$ because then the power of $2$ becomes to big.

Comment: Note that $2^{28}\times 3^{15}\times 5^2$ is slightly less than $10^{17}$ but $2^{57}$ ia slightly greater.  It follows that you need $2^{28}$ as the power of $2$.  Now you just need to apportion the rest of the terms (much easier).

Comment: Give $2^{28} \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13$ a whirl.