# The smallest number with given number of divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm looking for a formula which gives the smallest number such that the number of its divisors is known.
Exemple : let $n=2$ is the number of the divsors of $x$, then $x=2$ because 1 and 2 are a divisors of 2. Thanks.

Comment: What's the question?  Letting $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n$, are you asking "given $k$, what is the least natural number $n$ such that $d(n)=k$?"

Comment: Are you asking for the smallest number such that the number has a particular number of divisors?  The smallest number such that it has two divisors is $2$.  The smallest number such that it has three divisors is $4$.  The smallest number such that it has four divisors is $6$, etc?

Comment: If so, then see http://oeis.org/A005179

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: @JMoravitz beat me to the OEIS ref :)

Comment: I wouldn't expect a sensible formula for that.

Comment: So there is not an exact formula for this?

Comment: You mean a formula for the smallest number having a given number of digits ? No, there is no such "nice" formula. But a huge list of highly composite numbers exists and at least partially answers this question upto very high numbers of divisors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smallest number with specific number of divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496494/smallest-number-with-specific-number-of-divisors)

Comment: Examples: [24](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217233), [40](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888946), [1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729677), [1392](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318307)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

For prime $n$ the smallest number is obviously $2^{n-1}$.

For products of two prime numbers: $n=\pi_1\cdot \pi_2$ ($\pi_1\ge \pi_2$) it is $2^{\pi_1-1}3^{\pi_2-1}$  and so on but with growing complications.

The art of complications is the following. Based on the previous examples one can naively assume that the general expression for the number in question is
$$
M(n)=\prod_{i=1}^N p_i^{\pi_i-1},\tag{1}
$$ 
where $p_i$ are the prime numbers $2,3,5,\dots$ and $\pi_i$ are (not necessarily distinct) prime divisors of $n$:
$$
n=\prod_{i=1}^N\pi_i,\quad\text{with}\quad \pi_{i+1}\le\pi_i.
$$

And indeed an application of the expression (1) gives correctly almost all first 42 members of [A005179](http://oeis.org/A005179) with notable exceptions for $n=8,16,24,$ and $32$.

It is not hard to understand the reason for the exceptions. Consider the number $M(n)$ with $n$ having more than two prime factors and ask: what would happen if we remove in (1) the last prime $p_N$ and instead increase the power of 2? Then we shall look whether
$$
2^{\pi_1\pi_N-1}<2^{\pi_1-1}p_N^{\pi_N-1}\Rightarrow 
\pi_1\pi_N-1<\pi_1-1+(\pi_N-1)\log_2p_N\Rightarrow \pi_1<\log_2p_N.
$$
And this is exactly what happens in the case of $n=8$:
$$
\pi_1=2<\log_25=\log_2 p_3.
$$
This is not yet the end of story as besides increasing the power of 2 one can play also with simultaneous increasing it for 2 and 3, for 2, 3 and 5 and so on. It can be however conjectured that the "density" of the exceptions from (1) is generally rather low.